# Why is my C destructor not getting called?

Tags: c, constructor, destructor

I have two parts of my project: an `example.c` (which contains our main function) and an `api.c` (which contains all APIs). They are compiled separately, and the binaries generated by the API are used by the example to successfully make API calls.

I have set up both libraries to contain a constructor *and* destructor:

```
example.c

__attribute__((constructor)) static void example_constructor() {
  printf("constructor: example\n");
  api_setup();
}

__attribute__((destructor)) static void example_destructor() {
  printf("destructor: example\n");
  api_teardown();
}

int main() {
  // make API calls
}
```

```
api.c

__attribute__((constructor)) static void api_constructor() {
  printf("constructor: api\n");
}

__attribute__((destructor)) static void api_destructor() {
  printf("destructor: api\n");
}

api_setup() {
  // malloc a buffer to be used in the API calls
}

api_teardown() {
  // read + perform task on buffer. send to output file
  // free buffer
}

// other API definitions to manipulate the buffer
```

When set up like the above, constructors and destructors get called for both the example and API (at the start/end of example's main). Things work great but I'd like to have the `api.c` constructor/destructor responsible for all setup and teardown work. If I make changes:

```
api.c

__attribute__((constructor)) static void api_constructor() {
  printf("constructor: api\n");
  api_setup(); // doing setup in api.c constructor instead of example.c constructor
}

__attribute__((destructor)) static void api_destructor() {
  printf("destructor: api\n");
  api_teardown(); // doing teardown in api.c destructor instead of example.c destructor
}

// other API definitions to manipulate the buffer (including setup/teardown)
```

With the setup moved to the `api.c` constructor, I find that constructors get called for both `example.c` *and* `api.c`, but the destructor *only* gets called for `example.c`.

Why is this? And how could I go about performing all setup/teardown via the `api.c` constructor/destructor?

Comment: First of all, you don't really have any control over the order in which the destructor (or constructor) functions will be called. Secondly, are you sure that `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is not itself closed in a destructor function, and that it might be closed when one of your functions is called?

Comment: How _exactly_ do you find the lack of a destructor call? What compiler do you use and with flag flags? `__attribute__` is non-standard.

Comment: I guess I don't exactly know that stdout is not closed. I just find it weird that both destructor `printf` calls are made in example (1), but are not made in example (2). 

The api_teardown() function isn't called in the destructor as there is no output. Unless the function called by the destructor is unable to write to a file.

I would assume that the destructor fires when the object is unloaded so this behavior confuses me. Also, I am using clang compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure structuring your application this way is the best plan. Having explicit calls to initiate the shutdown process, then hooking these in to where such behaviour is required, as in inside a signal handler, or at the end of a run loop, makes it much easier to understand what's going on. Code like this is a lot like a "COMES FROM" call, nothing initiates it, it just "magically" executes, which can be frustrating for those trying to debug something.

Comment: Whats wrong with calling a `init` function at the begin of `main`? Within the initialization routine, the lib could register destructor calls via [atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) (which guarantees the functions be called in reverse order they were registered).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you have

Comment: `both libraries` is the library a shared library? Please post real full code with all the commands you used to compile and all the outputs of commands and operating system and compiler version and options you used. `I find that constructors` And you find that because there is no output? Please try using a syscall `write(STDERR, "stuff\n")`.

Comment: @tadman And another problem - if the code in `api_teardown()` is critical and must be run, it won't be if the process ends abnormally (as you implied with your comment about signal handlers).  IMO, though, constructors like this are useful for simple initializations that *de facto* never fail, such as initializing a mutex with something other than the default `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, I agree about constructors, but I think there's a slow descent into misery and madness if you start leveraging destructors too heavily.

Comment: Why is `atexit` not considered? It performs a teardown, where clean-ups can happen, in object-oriented paradigm, "destructor". The issue that I see with this code - is making C something that is outside the realm of the language, as in, adding object-oriented features, constructors, destructors, sure it can be hacked but that is implementation defined based on the startup code which gets linked in to produce a final executable. This is looking a rather painful setup of code scaffolding.

Comment: You could try setting a debugger break point in the function in question and see if it is triggered. This could resolve the "not being called" vs "printf no longer functional at this stage of program shutdown" question.

Comment: @tadman *a slow descent into misery and madness* You sure you're not describing programming in general?  ;-)

Comment: @AviBerger Or just use something like `strace` (on Linux) and see if/when the standard file descriptors get closed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Perhaps I should have said this *accelerates* said descent.

Answer (score 3):

Using this attribute in gcc you can control the priority of the constructors/destructors.

- for `constructor` smaller number means a higher priority
- for `destructor` smaller number means a lower priority

```
void __attribute__((constructor(101))) c1(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((constructor(102))) c2(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((constructor(103))) c3(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((constructor(104))) c4(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}

void __attribute__((destructor(101))) d1(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((destructor(102))) d2(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((destructor(103))) d3(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}
void __attribute__((destructor(104))) d4(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__);}

void main(void)
{
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9aGnnW487

Comment: The question asserts that one of the destructors doesn't get called at all, and asks why that is so.  I'm not seeing how this answer responds to that.